# Error when using debugger - `require': no such file to load -- ruby-debug (LoadError)'

Tags: ruby, debugging, ruby-1.8

I created a breakpoint in the code below. When I run it in windows cmd using
`ruby test.rb`, I get the error `in`require': no such file to load -- ruby-debug (LoadError)`
Why does this error happen and how do I fix it ?

```
class Dog
    def initialize(name)
        @name = name
    end

    def bark
        puts "bow"
        puts "wow"
        puts "wow"
    end
end

require 'ruby-debug'
debugger

d1 = Dog.new("d1")
d2 = Dog.new("d2")

puts "d1 says: " 
d1.bark
puts
puts "d2 says: " 
d2.bark
```

Someone had also installed ruby 1.8 on my computer before. So I am not sure if this could be responsible. When i invoke `gem install debugger` from the test.rb folder, I get the error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing debugger:
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb extconf.rb failed Could not create
>   Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
>   libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. 
>   You may need configuration options.

Comment: WTF ? Why is there a  -1 for no reason ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the? [Ruby Devkit](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/) ? The instructions for installing it [are here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) .

Comment: Installing the devkit is different from installing Ruby, when you install Ruby the dev-kit isn't installed, you need to do it separately. The devkit is necessary for building native extensions. I've had these errors appearwhen installing gems like you had and found out the hard way it was because it's the dev-kit that helps build native extensions.

Comment: My bad. I'll try installing it now and get back. thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept this as best answer if this worked for you. Let me know in case it doesn't, would be glad to help.

Comment: Its a nightmare to install ruby this way. In the link you gave, i runt the verfication step given in the end. I get an error that nmake is not available on my system. I google and find out that nmake comes with visual studio. I install several free versions and still dont get the nmake. I wasted so much time. I found a nmake project by alcatel-lucent for win server 2003 or above. No installation instructions for win. Tried to use it and failed. This is a mess.

Comment: Weird, it shouldn't be this way. It should be simple as this: https://forwardhq.com/support/installing-ruby-windows

Comment: thanks. I am running the command `gem install forward`. What does it do ? 
The command is taking too long. Not sure if its necessary

Comment: um that's just an example gem. To see if devkit is truly working, try install nokogiri 'gem install nokogiri'